# go malformed import path empty path element

Tags: go

Trying to run

> go mod init `pwd`

On a trivial example

```
    package main
    import (
        "net/http"
        "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    )

func main() {
// Echo instance
e := echo.New()


// Route => handler
e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!\n")
})

// Start server
e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

Gives an error

> go malformed import path (path to file) empty path element

Yet if I create a manual go.mod like this

```
module <path>

go 1.12

require github.com/labstack/echo/v4 v4.1.6
```

Then I can build / run the code normally.

Any idea why go mod init fails?
Mostly for future reference as creating the go.mod solves the immediate issue.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with go mod init `pwd`? If you're trying to create a module for the current folder, then you can just do `go mod init`. Adding `pwd` fails because modules can't be absolute paths.

Comment: Trying to get go.mod for current folder. if I try just `go mod init` I get 
`go: cannot determine module path for source directory /dir/path (outside GOPATH, module path must be specified)`. Likely because my code is not in GOPATH; have done the pwd method in the past with no issues so puzzled why it doesn't work this time.

Comment: When you do go mod init pwd (hopefully without the backticks), what is the error you get? Or you don't get no error and only once you try running your app you get the malformed thing? If you don't get no error from init, can you show the generated go.mod file?

Comment: Without argument `go mod init` is not guaranteed to succeed: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#why-does-go-mod-init-give-the-error-cannot-determine-module-path-for-source-directory

Comment: @mkopriva when I run with pwd (with backticks.. basically to point to current folder) I get the error: `go malformed import path empty path element`.
I have done the same method for go mod init in the past with no issues so  confused what about this folder / case is different.

Comment: @Francisco1844 "with backticks.. to point to current to current folder" is that an actual thing? I'm not saying without backticks it will suddenly work for you, but do backticks mean "do `go mod init` in current folder" because without backticks it would do it in a differrent folder than the current one?

Comment: I have to admit I haven't read all the stuff that's out there on go modules, not even that which I should, but the little bit I did read did not mention backticks in any way, is that a shell thing?

Comment: @mkopriva yes it is a shell execution method. It just executes whatever it is in the backticks so say you are in /some/folder then \`pwd` will be /some/folder

Comment: well that's embarrasing, thanks for the clarification @Francisco1844

Comment: @Francisco1844: `go mod init` takes a module name argument (which must be a valid import path), not a path argument (`usage: go mod init [module]`). You can't have a module name starting with `/`, so you were previously creating broken modules and the go command is now telling you that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the modules in the console. The syntax for that is `go mod init <mod_name>` where mod_name can be github.com/labstack/echo/v4.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, go mod init  but without / at the beginning of your path works. Perhaps outside of GOPATH relative paths should be used instead of absolute paths(?)